# "Плитка" чи "кахлі"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми, іменники

СУМ містить статтю

> [КА́ХЛІ](http://sum.in.ua/s/kakhli), ів, мн. (одн. кахель, хля, чол.;
>   кахля, і, жін.). **Керамічні *плитки* для личкування печей, стін
>   будівель і т. ін.** *Піч була з зелених водолазьких кахлів*
>   (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 320); *Піч і стіни до половини
>   викладені бездоганною, сніжно-білою кахлею* (Ірина Вільде, Пов. і
>   опов., 1949, 254); *У Києві в XVII столітті переважали типи ліпних
>   кахлів, политих зеленою або коричневою поливою* (Народна творчість та
>   етнографія, 3, 1968, 81).

Значення тлумачиться через ***`плитку`***, стаття на яку пропонує відповідно

> [ПЛИТКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/plytka), и, жін.
>   1. **Зменш.-пестл. до *плита*** 1, 2. *Краєм саду йшла викладена камінними плитками доріжка* (Ірина Вільде, Сестри.., 1958, 436).
>
> [ПЛИТА́](http://sum.in.ua/s/plyta), и, жін.
>   1. **Великий плоский (перев. прямокутний) з гладенькою поверхнею шматок каменю, металу і т. ін**. *Ясько мав собі.. функцію — розтирати
>   фарби на кам'яних плитах* (Іван Франко, IV, 1950, 211); *Стіл
>   фрезерного верстата — це чавунна плита* (Методика викладання фрезерної
>   справи, 1958, 142);
>
> //  **Такий шматок, оброблений для настилання тротуарів, площ,
>   облицювання стін і т. ін.** *Чи не піти до міста? Ще здалеку радо
>   стрічаю рожеві плити міської площі* (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955,
>   411); *На березі Іст-рівера будинок, Мов обеліск з гранітних плит і
>   скла* (Любомир Дмитерко, Осінь.., 1959, 18); *Облицювальна плита*.

Google пошук видає близько 62 тис. результатів на [плитка облицювальна](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5702j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0) і майже 59 тис. на [кахлі](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D1%96&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D1%96&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2301j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Утім, якщо подивитись на результати пошуку за зображеннями, то можна помітити що зображення для [кахлі](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D1%96&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVwoeD35DUAhXlYZoKHUE3BQEQsAQIOw) ближчі до того, що позначається російським ***`изразцы`***, на відміну від зображень для [плитка облицювальна](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0&biw=1920&bih=974&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDuuLH3pDUAhXCA5oKHYilDTIQsAQIQg).

Тож чи ***`плитка`*** і ***`кахлі`*** абсолютні синоніми, чи між ними є якась семантична або контекстуальна різниця?

Comment: Вікіпедія має дві різні статті [кахель](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) - "тонкі випалені керамічні плитки прямокутної форми, якими облицьовують стіни, печі, басейни, підлоги будинків." та [кахлі, кахля](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D1%96) - "художньо-декоративний **кахель**, що використовується для облицювання печей, стін осель і палаців, фонтанів тощо".

Comment: @Artemix, можете, будь ласка, пояснити як для дівчинки, в чому різниця?

Comment: (оффтопік) *«Google пошук видає близько 62 тис. результатів на плитка облицювальна»* — от тепер Ґуґлореклама вам протягом кількох років навʼязуватиме і плитку, і кахлі. :-)

Comment: @bytebuster, (оффтопік) я тут ремонт квартири роблю, то плитка й кахлі не найстрашніше, що мені буде пропонувати гугльреклама протягом наступних років)))

Comment: @Artemix, якщо вірити ось [цьому,](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%CA%C0%D5%C5%CB%DC) то *кахлі* це просто множина від *кахель*.

Comment: Я згоден з вашим словником, але здивований Вікіпедією, ось і з вами поділився.

Comment: @Artemix, дякую, що поділились! Це був додатковий привід зазирнути до словника)

Comment: Власне у питанні все і розписано "плитка" більш широке поняття вона може бути пластиковою, металічною, тощо, а кахель є окремим видом плитки - керамічна плитка.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Див. пояснення нижче]

- **Плитка** — невеличка плита.
- Плитка може бути **для личкування (облицювання)** або іншого призначення.
- Плитка для личкування може бути з кераміки (тоді її називають **кахелем**, **кахлею**, **кахлями**, але можна вживати і ширшого значення слова) або інших матеріалів.

Comment: Яка візуалізація! Дякую! Щоправда, дещо здивована, що *личкування/личкувати* = *облицювання/облицьовувати*. Утім, [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/lychkuvaty) спростував мої сумніви. До сьогодні знала лише про одне значення *личкувати* (перше в СУМ), причому в досить специфічному контексті: *личкувати кишки на ковбаси* 
 = чистити кишки ізсередини, наступна стадія після прання кишок (пам'ятаю ще з далекого дитинства, коли у бабусі в селі кололи свиней).

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, а є ще варіант «оздоблювати». Хоча декілька місяців тому (ну, я робив відповідь раніше, просто вона залежалася на ЖД) я прийшов висновку, що це не зовсім те саме (не повний синонім). Але вже забув чому (здається, щось мало ширший набір змістів, мабуть, саме «оздоблювати»). Зате тепер буду знати про личкування кишок на ковбаси :).

Comment: А [тут](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/Ponomarov_Anatolii/Ukrainska_mynuvshyna.pdf) є інше значення *личкування* - "традиційний спо­сіб підтвердження злочину шляхом осо­бистого засвідчення та речових доказів. Звичаєве право вимагало, щоб лице (тоб­то річ) було показано ще до суду комусь із сільської влади...". Взагалі, дуже цікаве джерело за посиланням.